# Start YouTrack in docker container on linux

Tags: docker, youtrack

I try install YouTrack in docker on my linux machine

1. I create folders

> sudo mkdir -p -m 750 /opt/youtrack/data /opt/youtrack/conf
>   /opt/youtrack/logs /opt/youtrack/backups

2. I set permissions

> sudo chown -R 13001:13001 /opt/youtrack/data /opt/youtrack/conf
>   /opt/youtrack/logs /opt/youtrack/backups

and

```
sudo chmod 750 /opt/youtrack/backups
sudo chown 13001:13001 /opt/youtrack/backups
```

I try start docker

```
sudo docker run jetbrains/youtrack:2018.1.39916
=== WARNING! WARNING! WARNING! ========================================================================== (start warning)
Non-anonymous volume should has been mapped to folder /opt/youtrack/conf inside container (in non-demo environment)
(as well as non-anonymous volumes to directories /opt/youtrack/data, /opt/youtrack/logs and /opt/youtrack/backups).
Otherwise, application data stored outside container on host machine (if any) is ignored.
Changed made to configuration parameters and application data during this run would be applied to the container local volume only
and won't be reused if product run inside another container
(after container was recreated either for normal run or for upgrade).
See help for more details on what directories inside container should be mapped as non-anonymous volumes and why
=========================================================================================================== (end warning)
Starting YouTrack...
* Configuring JetBrains YouTrack 2018.1
* Made default base-url 'http://1811fd622e49:8080/' from hostname '1811fd622e49' and listen port '8080'
* JetBrains YouTrack 2018.1 runtime environment is successfully configured
[YouTrack Error] Failed to start JetBrains YouTrack 2018.1 due to unexpected exception: Native random generator does not seem to have enough entropy for JetBrains YouTrack 2018.1 to start.
[YouTrack Error] You can fix it by switching to PRNG (with -Djava.security.egd=/dev/zrandom) or by reconfiguring your operation system to provide more random bits.
YouTrack process finished
Launcher is exiting
```

I tried fix it like this article [link](https://www.howtoforge.com/helping-the-random-number-generator-to-gain-enough-entropy-with-rng-tools-debian-lenny)

but it not halped.

In first time I start this container on 8080 port successful but I try change port(remove container and try start on new port). Now I try on 8080 or 7777 I get error

Answer (score 1):

Created app data directories (in your case `/opt/youtrack/data`, `/opt/youtrack/conf`, `/opt/youtrack/logs`, `/opt/youtrack/backups`) should be mapped to Youtrack container on every run.
But before running, YouTrack should be configured to use another entropy source.

For this execute the following command first:

```
docker run --rm -it \
-v /opt/youtrack/conf:/opt/youtrack/conf \
-v /opt/youtrack/logs:/opt/youtrack/logs \
jetbrains/youtrack:2018.1.39916 \
configure -J-Djava.security.egd=/dev/zrandom
```

As a result, jvm option `-Djava.security.egd` will be stored into YouTrack config file inside mapped volume `/opt/youtrack/conf`

Then, container can be started with help of the following command:

```
docker run -it --name YouTrack-Instance \
-v /opt/youtrack/data:/opt/youtrack/data \
-v /opt/youtrack/conf:/opt/youtrack/conf \
-v /opt/youtrack/logs:/opt/youtrack/logs \
-v /opt/youtrack/backups:/opt/youtrack/backups \
-p 8080:8080 \
jetbrains/youtrack:2018.1.39916
```

See details on how to start and configure YouTrack docker container in [official documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/youtrack-docker-installation.html)

Comment: Is this still the case? Currently the documentation says to use the web interface for the initial setup, and these step only to configure from the command line and/or to change the base URL. Also, why would YouTrack need another source of entropy?